# Picking Random Cell, Ignoring empty

Tags: google-apps-script, random, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula

My coding skills aren't the best, but I know somewhat how to use excel/sheets.

I am trying to get a cell to select a random cell in a column, but ignore cells that are empty. So fare, I can get it to select a random cell, but how do I make it continue if the cell is empty?

More specifically, I had an idea for a game to play at an event based on the Magic the gathering game mode: Horde, and use Google Sheet as the "enemy" deck. The below link is just sample. Not the actual idea.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XKMCguvpI_4PDtBYVXa4_FaH7O3WgckRWYbQ75_5F7E/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use:

```
=INDEX(SORT(FILTER({RANDARRAY(G3:G), G3:G}, L3:L=TRUE)), 1, 2)
```

to get random ID 1 or ID 9

[image: 0]

`=TRUE` can be changed to `<>""` to simulate empty cell

---

for puppy name:

```
=VLOOKUP(INDEX(SORT(FILTER({RANDARRAY(G3:G), G3:G}, L3:L=TRUE)), 1, 2), G:H, 2, 0)
```

or just:

```
=INDEX(SORT(FILTER({RANDARRAY(G3:G), H3:H}, L3:L=TRUE)), 1, 2)
```

Comment: Seems like the first one works awesomely. It ignores the criteria I was looking for and only selects data associated with the selection. I am guessing it is the RANDARRAY that randomly picks from the range. Thanks a ton Player0 :D .. Not sure what to use the last two for though. Seems like they randomly checks for names from A17:D19.

Comment: Question though: how does it check the "active" and "discard" area? I don't see any refence to these cells.

Comment: to exclude active and discard area you need: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHSN2.png

Comment: Oh no, I don't want to exlude them. I was just wondering how it could check them without having the cells mentioned anywhere. Especially since the sheet I posted was a demo, and I had plans to expand the area for discarded and active cards.

Comment: then I guess I misunderstood whats "take out of the deck" means

Comment: That is possible. I have been told my that my explanations sometimes can be confusing. But the code works and I can see where it draws the data from. But I am still curious how the first code could find it since there was no reference to the two areas.

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*You can define the column as a range, push only non-empty cells to an array and select a random element.*

#### Code:

Under the assumption that the column you want to select is column `A` in a sheet called `Sheet1`, and starts from `A`:

```js
function selectRandomCell() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("A1:A").getValues();
  var values = [];
  
  for (var i = 0; i < range.length; i++) {
    if (range[i][0] == "") {
      continue;
    }
    else {
      values.push(range[i][0]);
    }
  }

  return values[Math.floor(Math.random() * values.length)]);
}
```

You can change the range as you need, however.

Comment: Like the first suggestion, I am not sure what that does or even where to place that. Seems like there is more to these sheets than the obvious coding.

Answer (score 0):

```
function pickANonEmptyRandomCellFromARange() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  const rg=sh.getDataRange();
  const vs=rg.getDisplayValues();
  let v=[];
  //This loops through all of the rows r stands for the row element  is the index
  vs.forEach(function(r,i){
    //this loops through each column and c stands for the cell element  j is the index
    r.forEach(function(c,j) {
      //this asks if the cell is not blank thee push the A1Notation into an array
      if(c){v.push(sh.getRange(i+1, j+1).getA1Notation());}
    });
  });
  //This is a dialog which displays v[random index] which is the A1 Notation of the selected element. 
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(v[Math.floor(Math.random()*v.length)]), 'Random Non Empty Cell');
}
```

Comment: That does not look like a normal sheet coding, so can't really see what it is trying to do.

Comment: I put some comments in there to assist you.  Sorry I thought it was pretty straiight forward.  You might want to spend a little more time learning ES6 because the later versions of Javascript can get rather cryptic since many commands can be strung out into one line. And I normally don't use any comments.